# Automapper IMapper issues with Dependency Resolver

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, automapper

I'm trying to use automapper and have some issues when trying to resolve a mapper object.

This is the code

```
 public class MapAdapter : IMyMapper
 {
        private readonly AutoMapper.IMapper _mapper;

        public MapAdapter(AutoMapper.IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

public TDest Map<TSource, TDest>(TSource source)
        {
            try
            {
                return _mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>(source);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

And this is the exception

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate
>   'Infrastructure.Mapper.Adapter.MapAdapter'.

If i remvoe the AutoMapper.Mapper dependency from constructor

```
public MapAdapter()
```

everything works, except for the Automapper `_mapper` field which of course is null

This is the DI configuration, where IMyMapper is my interface, and MapAdapter is the Implementation of IMyMapper

```
_serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMyMapper, MapAdapter>();
```

I have a mapping profile which is empty

```
  public class OrderDataMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public OrderDataMappingProfile()
        {
        }
    }
```

any idea why this fails ?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: @MCR, any reason why you unselected my answer as the correct answer?

Comment: sorry, no. it is the preferred answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occours because you haven't registered a mapper which should be resolved on the IMapper interface on the service collection.

To solve it, add the mapping profile to a new mapper configuration and then create a mapper from that and bind it to the collection.

```
var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new OrderDataMappingProfile ());
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Comment: Is it possible that you will explain why you use Singleton in your example?